# Run-time error '1004': Application-Defined or Object defined error

Tags: vba, excel, autofill

I'm pretty new to VBA and am having some issues regarding my Autofill lines.
Specifically, I'm having issues with this line:

Worksheets("Batches").Range("C2").AutoFill Destination:=Worksheets("Batches").Range("C2:C" & F)

My full code is below and if anyone could help, that would be greatly appreciated!

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

Worksheets("Batches").Activate


Dim F As Long
lastRow = Worksheets("Batches").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row
Worksheets("Batches").Range("C2").AutoFill Destination:=Worksheets("Batches").Range("C2:C" & F)
Worksheets("Batches").Range("D2").AutoFill Destination:=Worksheets("Batches").Range("D2:D" & F)


Worksheets("Batches").Range("A:A").Copy
Worksheets("Batches").Range("G:G").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
Worksheets("Batches").Range("D:D").Copy
Worksheets("Batches").Range("H:H").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

Columns("G:H").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batches").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batches").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "H2:H1048576"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batches").Sort
    .SetRange Columns("G:H")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With



Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True
```

Comment: You do not assign a value to F so it will be zero.

Comment: I think you meant to use your lastRow variable instead of F